# What is the best Linux file system to use for MySql?

Tags: linux, mysql, filesystems

When setting up a dedicated MySql server, what is the best Linux file system to use? Are there any I should avoid?

The data partition will be on a simple Raid 1 mirror (in hardware).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021854/what-is-the-best-linux-filesystem-for-mysql-innodb.  Can we do cross-site dupes?

> You should have a look at [Lessons Learned in Building a Highly Scalable MySQL Database](http://www.mysqlconf.com/mysql2008/public/schedule/detail/625). They benchmarked mysql with some of these filesystems and jfs looks like a clear the winner.

Comment: Haha... I figured this would have been answered, but I couldn't find it when I searched. I didn't think to search stackoverflow for dupes. Maybe some of those questions need to be ported over?

Comment: Personally I think that the sites all being the same would suit me just fine :)